# htaccess, always a GET value

Tags: .htaccess

So I have this in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^page(?:/error(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ page.php?error=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I always get an empty array which is error="". Anything above page/ should be optional, yet it's setting error in $_GET array to nothing.

`Array ( [error] => )`

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page(?:/error(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ page.php?error=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have `MultiViews` on.

Add this line on top of your .htaccess to turn it off:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

**UPDATE:** Full .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^register(?:/error(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ /register.php?error=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Still the same. I've updated the OP with the full htaccess also.

Comment: Provided you complete .htaccess, try it now.

Comment: Still doing the same.

Comment: Made another edit. Make sure there is no other conflicting rule OR any other .htaccess

Comment: Okay, it's still there but I guess it's somewhere in my code which I can't seem to find. I will just have to use a workaround. Thanks though.

Comment: What is the full URL you're opening in browser?

Comment: Sorry, that's the page I meant I was going to. Then I've basically `if(isset($_GET['error'])) { print_r($_GET); }` and it shows what is in the original post.